# Error: Cannot assign QObject* to QQuickItem*

Tags: qt, list, object, qml

I get this error when I try to show either a dialog or a popup in a tab. I don't understand why. In other apps I've made, it works, but I cannot see the difference between them.

What am I doing wrong?

I made an example code which has the exact same issue:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import Ubuntu.Components.ListItems 0.1 as ListItem
import Ubuntu.Components.Popups 0.1
MainView {
// objectName for functional testing purposes (autopilot-qt5)
objectName: "mainView"

// Note! applicationName needs to match the .desktop filename 
applicationName: "testar"

/* 
 This property enables the application to change orientation 
 when the device is rotated. The default is false.
*/
automaticOrientation: true

width: units.gu(50)
height: units.gu(75)

Tabs {
    id: tabs

    // First tab begins here
    Tab {
        objectName: "Tab1"

        title: i18n.tr("Hello..")

        // Tab content begins here
        page: Page {
            Column {
                width: parent.width
                ListItem.Standard {
                    text: i18n.tr("Swipe from right to left to change tab.")
                }
            }
            // coordinates popover
            Component {
                    id: popoverComponent

                    Popover {
                        id: popover
                        Column {
                            id: containerLayout
                            anchors {
                                left: parent.left
                                top: parent.top
                                right: parent.right
                            }
                            ListItem.Header { text: "Standard list items" }
                            ListItem.Standard { text: "Do something" }
                            ListItem.Standard { text: "Do something else" }
                            ListItem.Header { text: "Buttons" }
                            ListItem.SingleControl {
                                highlightWhenPressed: false
                                control: Button {
                                    text: "Do nothing"
                                    anchors {
                                        fill: parent
                                        margins: units.gu(1)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ListItem.SingleControl {
                                highlightWhenPressed: false
                                control: Button {
                                    text: "Close"
                                    anchors {
                                        fill: parent
                                        margins: units.gu(1)
                                    }
                                    onClicked: PopupUtils.close(popover)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            tools: ToolbarActions {
                // Show spawn again
                Action {
                    objectName: "action1"
                    id: action1

                    iconSource: Qt.resolvedUrl("toolbarIcon.png")
                    text: i18n.tr("Reload")

                    onTriggered: {
                        console.debug('Debug: Reload data')
                        PopupUtils.open(popoverComponent, action1)
                    }
                }
        }
        }
    }

    // Second tab begins here
    Tab {
        objectName: "Tab2"

        title: i18n.tr("..Toolbar!")
        page: Page {
            tools: ToolbarActions {
                Action {
                    objectName: "action"

                    iconSource: Qt.resolvedUrl("toolbarIcon.png")
                    text: i18n.tr("Tap me!")

                    onTriggered: {
                        label.text = i18n.tr("Toolbar tapped")
                    }
                }
            }

            Column {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                Label {
                    id: label
                    objectName: "label"

                    text: i18n.tr("Swipe from bottom to up to reveal the toolbar.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working! The thing was that I tried to show a dialog, or whatever, by clicking on the toolbar - which is something else then the other stuff in the actual window.

So I just changed the ID in the toolbar onTriggered, to a item in the window, which in this case was a WebView with id: owMap. Old id is the one two rows up and commented out.

Now it works!

```
                // Change coordinates
                Action {
                    id: coordinateAction
                    objectName: "action2"

                    iconSource: Qt.resolvedUrl("toolbarIcon.png")
                    text: i18n.tr("Coordinates")

                    onTriggered: {
                        //PopupUtils.open(dialog, coordinateAction)
                        PopupUtils.open(cooDialog, owMap)
                        console.debug('Debug: Change coordinates pressed')
                    }
                }
```